# Can't access class from .Net standard project in Blazor WASM project

Tags: blazor, .net-standard, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor client side project.
Put my ContactInfo class in another project, .Net standard.

Now in my razor file in my Blazor project I can't access the class property from ContactInfo(from the .Net standard project), I also made a class called ExampleModel in my Blazor project and there are no problems accessing the properties from the ExampleModel.

Need help to understand why my Blazor project can't access properties of a created class from another .net standard project?
I've written some comments in the code below in the  to explain the problem.
Thanks for your help.

```html
@page "/todo2"
    <head>
        <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    
      <div class="bg-img">

        <EditForm Model="@contactInfo"  OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" class="container">

            <InputText class="textRuta" PlaceHolder="Namn" id="name" @bind-Value="contactInfo.NoProperty shows upp here???" />
            
            <InputText class="textRuta" PlaceHolder="Email" id="email" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Email, works well when I use Model="exampleModel in beginning EditForm" />
            

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            
            </div>

        </EditForm>
    </div>
    
    
    
    @code {
        private ExampleModel exampleModel = new ExampleModel();

        private ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();

        private void HandleValidSubmit()
        {

        }
    }
```

emphasized text

Comment: Did you add a reference from the project that contains the class to your current project? If you've done that already, did you include the model in the form with `@using [class_name_space]`?

Comment: My blazor project has a reference to the .net standard project called LandingPage.Models, 

In the @code part I used private LandingPage.Models.ContactInfo contactInfo = new LandingPage.Models.ContactInfo(); instead of just ContactInfo, that did the trick. 

If i use EditForm Model="@LandingPage.Models.ContactInfo" I get the error "ContactInfo is a type which is not valid in the given context"